# i have one user on system and its administrator but error git is about user

Tags: github, gitlab, administrator

in git, which i installed on my system, when i write any command, it gives me this message:

```
$ git add .
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'G:/'
'G:/' is owned by:
        'S-1-5-18'
but the current user is:
        'S-1-5-21-1248128802-4178677448-3018538387-1001'

To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory G:/
```

also, my system has one user and it is administrator.
By adding the last line of code, the problem is solved, but what can I do to solve the problem fundamentally and in all drives